# Disqus plugin not work in ionic v1

Tags: angularjs, disqus, ionic-v1

I am using Disqus in my ionic v1 project. The browser is working fine but the problem after build apk is not working show me the error
'we were unable to load Disqus. If you are a moderator please see our Troubleshooting guide'

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var disqus_shortname = 'shortname';
(function() {   
var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; 
dsq.async = true;
dsq.src = 'https://'+disqus_shortname+'.disqus.com/embed.js';
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
  })();
</script>


<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
```

Comment: What does the "Troubleshooting guide" say?

Comment: thank you for the reply troubleshooting guide link is https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472007-i-m-receiving-the-message-%22we-were-unable-to-load-disqus-%22